# Compact and marker values on SVG display values

Tags: css, svg, attributes

So I was checking out the SVG [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#DisplayProperty) attribute and for my surprise, I've found two CSS2 deprecated values (at least for me), those are `compact` and `marker`. Does someone have got more info to the respect? If I'm not wrong, SVG and CSS share too many properties, but `compact` & `marker` values are deprecated since CSS3

this is text defined by the W3C

[image: W3C SVG <code>display</code> attribute definition]

Answer (score 0):

The [latest version of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#VisibilityControl) simply hands off the definition of display and visibility to CSS.

> See the CSS 2.1 specification for the definitions of display and visibility. [CSS2]

For display in SVG anything other than none is treated the same.

> Elements that have any other display value than none are rendered as normal.

Comment: What doubts? For SVG there's only none and not none. Everything other than none is treated the same.

Comment: So then ¿`compact` equals `run-in`?